# Using clojure filter with a dynamic function passed in

Tags: clojure

I am defining a function, which takes in an array that is to be reformatted to a function.
This returned function is the first argument to a filter command.
The second argument is this table which I have defined

```
(def persons '({:id 1 :name "olleš"} {:id 2 :name "anna"} {:id 3 :name "isak"} {:id 4 :name "beatrice"}))
```

When I run my filter command

```
seminar.core=> (filter (fn [word func arg] (func word arg)) [:id > 2] persons)
```

I receive this error

```
ArityException Wrong number of args (3) passed to: core/filter  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

I would like my filter function to behave similarly to this one below

```
(filter #(< (:id %) 2) persons)
({:id 1, :name "olle"})
```

Comment: When you fill in `:id`, `>` and `2` for `(fn [word func arg] (func word arg))`, it has no more arguments left -- where would you pass it the item being filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple stuff, I would just use an anonymous function:

```
(filter #(> (:id %) 2) persons) 

    => ({:id 3, :name "isak"} {:id 4, :name "beatrice"})
```

Another solution is to write a predicate-generating function, instead of doing it inline.

```
(defn build-pred
  [word func arg]
  (fn [item]
    (func (word item) arg)))

(filter (build-pred :id > 2) persons))

  => ({:id 3, :name "isak"} {:id 4, :name "beatrice"})
```

If you really want to pass in the args as a vector, just use destructuring:

```
(defn build-pred-vec
  [[word func arg]]
  (fn [item]
    (func (word item) arg)))

(filter (build-pred-vec [:id > 2]) persons)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for partial application:

```
(filter 
  (partial
    (fn [word func arg item] (func (word item) arg))
    :id > 2)
  persons)
```

Here, we create a *partially applied* version of the function that has `word`, `func` and `arg` already filled in, and leave another argument -- `item` -- open for the item being filtered.